# "Tonight is a work night"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"Tonight is a work night"

Source: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Work%20night&defid=9800761#9800761

"Work night" means

The night before a work day.

so,

"Tonight is a work night"

If "work night" is the night before a working day, what about "tonight is a working night"?
Does "working night" mean "a night when you have to work"?

Comment: "Work night" can also mean a night that one must work. It depends on context.

Comment: "Working night" is not a very common phrase, but if I, as an American English speaker, heard it, I would think it meant "night that I had to work", yes.

Answer (score 3):

"Tonight is a work night" is -- most likely -- an allusion to the more common phrase "Tonight is a school night".

"Tonight is a school night" is often used to indicate that one must get to bed early tonight in order to get up early tomorrow for school.

From Cambridge dictionary

**school night**
noun [ C ]
US  /ˈskuːl ˌnaɪt/ UK  /ˈskuːl ˌnaɪt/

the evening before a day when children have to go to school. Adults also use this expression informally to describe the evening before a day when they have to get up to go to work. :

```
I don't usually stay out this late on a school night.
```